# Where do I change mod settings?

Tags: dont-starve

Ive installed the Neat RGP Hub. In the description it says that it's possible to adjust the number of inventory slots, how big containers should be and so on but I can't find any settings to do this.

I tried in the mod and settings section of the main menu. and from the in game settings. Nowhere do I get any options specific to the mod. I have also checked the world options before starting the game.

Answer (score 2):

Oh.. ok. So go to the Mod section in the main menu and mouse over the mod you want to configure. IF it has a congiuration then a Config button will show upp. Just dont mouse over another mod cause then the button will dissapear.